# redirect a url including everything after the slash behind it?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Note: using example URLs

I have a URL `https://somesite.tv/shows/scary-movie` and want to make a rewrite in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^/?shows/(.*)$ shows/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /shows https://somesite.tv
```

But it only redirects with the URL is `/shows`

I want to also include anything after shows for example:

> https://somesite.tv/shows/scary-movie

should redirect to

> https://somesite.tv

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` looks pretty close. Maybe `RewriteRule ^shows/(.*)$ / [R=301,L]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/?shows/(.*)$ https://somesite.tv/shows/$1 [R=301,L]
```